# How to combine a static string with a dynamic slug in Next.js dynamic routes?

Tags: next.js, url-routing

I've tried to check through the official documentation, various issues, and inside SO previous questions, but I can't find confirmation if it's possible to create a dynamic route in Next.js that contains a constant or a string combined with a slug. For example?

```
pages/
  something-[slug].jsx
```

Is it possible or not? I'm inclined to think not because of the examples I've tried to build, but possibly I'm missing something.

Comment: pages/something-[slug].jsx looks like a static route

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While Next.js doesn't provide built-in support for partial dynamic routes (like `something-[slug]`), you can work around it by setting up an actual dynamic route and use [`rewrites`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) to map the incoming URL (in the format you want) to that route.

For instance, you could setup a dynamic route under `/pages/something/[slug].jsx`, then configure a `rewrites` rule in `next.config.js` as follows.

```js
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
    async rewrites() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/something-:slug',
                destination: '/something/:slug'
            }
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @juliomalves for your answer. It would not have occurred to me to explore that option. Unfortunately, it seems to be more complicated than initially thought for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

pages/
something-[slug].jsx

This worked just fine for me:

```js
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
    async rewrites() {
        return [
            {
                source: "/something-:slug",
                destination: "/something-[slug]",
            }
        ];
    }
}
```

localhost:3000/something-slug