# NextJS overlapping dynamic routes

Tags: javascript, next.js, url-routing

I have two dynamic routes specified in my NextJS app — `[pageId].tsx` and `job-[pageId].tsx`.

I would like the more specific route (in this case `job-[pageId].tsx`) to take precedence over the less specific route.

Currently though, all pages are being rendered by `[pageId].tsx`. Is there a way to adjust this or structure things differently to achieve this?

Comment: You can't have two dynamic routes at the same level. Also, you can't have partial dynamic routes either, but there are workarounds - see [For Next.js Dynamic Routes, it is possible to combine a string with a slug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72900622/for-next-js-dynamic-routes-it-is-possible-to-combine-a-string-with-a-slug).

Answer (score 0):

You try nextjs rewrites

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites

```
  async rewrites() {
const rewriteArray = [
  {       
    source: "/:id.html",
    destination: "/any/path/you/want/:id",
  },
];

return rewriteArray;}
```

Hope it helps!