# Can i create a Nextjs dynamic route [id]-[first_name]-[last_name]?

Tags: next.js, url-routing

I am using nextjs to build a directory. I effectively want to click on 'more info' and an info page to load under the URL of /info/[id]-[first_name]-[last_name].
I am pulling data from an api by id, which will then get the first_name and last_name data.

I have a file inside an info folder named [id]-[first_name]-[last_name] :

```
export default function Info({ info }) {
return (
    <div>
        <h1>First Name</h1>
        <p> Last Name </p>
    </div>
    );
}

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
const res = await fetch('http://xxx:1337/api/info');
const data = await res.json();

// map data to an array of path objects with params (id)
const paths = [data].map(info => {
    return {
        params: [{
            id: `${info.id}-`,
            first_name: `${info.first_name}-`,
            last_name: `${info.last_name}`
        }]
    }
})

return {
    paths,
    fallback: false
    }
}

export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
const id = context.params.id;
const res = await fetch('http://xxxx:1337/api/info/' + id);
const data = await res.json();

return {
    props: { info: data }
}
```

With this I just get the error:

***Error: A required parameter (id]-[first_name]-[last_name) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths for /info/[id]-[first_name]-[last_name]***

I guess that error is pretty self-explanatory, but I am blocked at this point. I have seen that i may be able to use a slug, but that means re-working a lot of the api.

Any direction with this is apprecated. Thanks!

Comment: You can't do that by default as you can't have routes in that format (`/info/[id]-[first_name]-[last_name]`). However, you could work around it by using `rewrites` and a route like `/info/[id]/[first_name]/[last_name]`. See [For Next.js Dynamic Routes, it is possible to combine a string with a slug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72900622/for-next-js-dynamic-routes-it-is-possible-to-combine-a-string-with-a-slug).

Answer (score 0):

in this way you can catch all attributes `/info/[id]/[first_name]/[last_name]`
by making the file  `/info/[...slug]`

```
export const getStaticProps = async ({ query }) => { 
         const [id ,firstname ,lastname] = query.slug }
```

or keep it `/info/[slug]` and get it as string after that you can split it